# Adding another function in an "App Designer" function

Tags: matlab, function, matlab-app-designer

I'm using App Designer in MATLAB. I have created a push button, 51-54 work no problem, then when I assigned another function into it (highlighted in the screenshot), it wouldn't work!

Please help me overcome this problem.

Screenshot showing the problem:

[image: Screenshot showing the problem]

Answer (score 0):

Problem: function inside of a  function the way it is written in the screenshot. 
4 things come up my mind:

1. Generally:

> yourApp.mlapp or any other code.m file

```
function  someProcess()
end

function subProcess()
end
```

---

2. In your case rather try to write your function in an second .m file and call it from within your your app.
   be sure to have it on the MATLAB path.

> yourApp.mlapp or any other code.m file

```
function someProcess()    
   subProcess();
end
```

> + external code.m file

```
function someProcess()    
   subProcess();
end
```

3. define your function as a public or private function (method) inside the app. ( for others: the block is not there by default. click: app designer> code view > function > add private function | add public function)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHaVv.png)

4. if your function is only used once you could also write an anonymous function

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html